# Authentication in Iframe APi Jitsi

Tags: jitsi, jitsi-meet

I have self-hosted Jitsi meet instance. I have also created an authentication. Now all I want is to pass the authentication parameter in IframeApi, the image below:

[image]

Instead of login from the displayed dialog box. I want to pass authentication from API. Help please, I tried but couldn't found any solutions here and there.

Comment: any news ? ....